# How do I compile vim with the --enable-gui=yes flag on OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, vi, open-source

I'm trying to compile the latest version of [`vim`](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/) (7.3.785 as on date) with the `--enable-gui` option set to `yes`:

```
./configure --enable-gui=yes
make
```

but `make` fails with several errors ([full output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=66GdCbZn)). I can't quite make sense of the errors, as I don't see anything specific that I can fix. I must add that compiling it works fine without the GUI option, so it might be something directly related to X or the OS X Cocoa frame work. I'm running OS X 10.8.2 on a retina MBP.

What should I change/add/install to get this to work?

> **Note:** This question is explicitly about compiling `vim` from source with the GUI option. I'm aware of [`macvim`](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/) and this is what I use for almost everything. However, in order to embed `vim` inside Eclipse using [`eclim`](http://eclim.org/), I need `gvim` (works out of the box on Windows and Linux). Unfortunately, `macvim` does not support embedding inside Eclipse, hence my attempts to make it work on OS X.

Comment: Did you try Homebrew? It would be very simple to edit the formula for vim (`brew edit vim`) and change the line `--enable-gui=no` to `--enable-gui=yes`. Your log suggests you might be missing some dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix the error about missing header files by exporting CFLAGS like this before running `make`:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon/"
```

Unfortunately, a new attempt to compile `vim` fails with loads of errors:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers/MacTypes.h:17:24: error: #include nested too deeply
(...)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:156: error: conflicting types for ‘Boolean’
/usr/X11/include/X11/Intrinsic.h:155: error: previous declaration of ‘Boolean’ was here
(...)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers/MacTypes.h:11:20: error: missing binary operator before token "("
(...)
```

and README_mac.txt doesn't offer much help:

```
(...)
Sorry, this text still needs to be written!
```

After some more failed attempts with other compile options, and after skimming through the errors, one quickly gets the impression that **GUI support is not yet implemented for OS X, at least for [Quartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_(graphics_layer))**.

A look to the other options for getting `vim`, HomeBrew and MacPorts, pretty much confirms the suspicion: The former doesn't offer GUI support at all (see [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/vim.rb)) and the latter only using X11 (see [here](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/editors/vim/Portfile)).

So to compile `vim` with GUI support you will have to revert to the good ol' X11 (I tested the Athena widgets, other options are `motif` and, if you use GTK, `gtk1` and `gtk2`):

```
$ make distclean
$ ./configure --enable-gui=yes --enable-gui=athena --disable-darwin
```

After launching [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org) I could start `vim` in GUI mode:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ ./src/vim -g
```

[image]

However, I have the impression that this is not the GUI support you need to embed `vim` inside Eclipse.

Comment: Although it doesn't work with Eclipse, this answers my question, so +1! Eclipse needs vim with gtk support, but I seem to be having issues compiling that as well. However, that's a different issue and looks like I might be able to fix it myself. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I could help, hopefully you can get `vim` to compile with GKT support.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [macports](https://www.macports.org/) to install `vim` with gtk support:

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/port install vim +huge +gtk2
```